# Bash command history is not written when a window is closed

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu

I found that the "bash for ubuntu for windows" installed on my laptop cannot load the command history once I reboot the "bash for ubuntu for windows".

More precisely, if I open the terminal, and input some commands, then all commands I inputted in this terminal session can be found by the arrow keys. But if I close (by clicking the "x" on the up right corner) the terminal and reopen it, I cannot find any command I typed before by the arrow keys.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just had a quick try. In my case (Creator's Update, 16.04 Ubuntu on WSL) the commands are saved when I use `exit`, but get lost when I use the top left button. Can you confirm this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks @bracco23 I will edit the question to specify that I click the "x" to close the window before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to leave the shell by typing `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> rather than just closing the window. `exit` will write the history implicitly, you can explicitly trigger a history write with `history -w` at any time.

Comment: That really works. Thank you very much! But I do not understand why in Mac & Linux terminal, I can just click the "x" to close, and then get all the command history stored, but in the bash for windows I have to use exit?

Comment: Looks like the way Windows terminates bash is different than on UNIX and bash has no chance to write the history. But maybe it is just a configuration issue? I cannot test it. I don't have Windows.

Comment: It's a long-standing (30 years?) Windows issue -- closing the prompt has never triggered a window close event like you get with any standard Windows application. All Windows command prompt programs suffer from the same issue; you have to store your settings as you go in Windows command prompt land.